# Dispatch touch event to a sibling view

Tags: android, touch

I have developped a custom layout that extends ViewGroup. Now, I want to use it in an activity. In my activity, I have both this layout and a viewpager inside a framelayout. My custom layout fills my Frame layout and is above my viewPager.

I would like to be able to handle click events on my custom layout and let all the other motions go to the viewpager so it can still scroll.

I haven't managed so far. Either I have the click but the viewpager cannot scroll anymore, or the contrary. I have overriden onTouchEvent and onInterceptTouchEvent.

What I notice is that, I correctly receive the down event on my custom layout, but once it has been catched by the viewpager, I do never get up there. How can I make communications between sibling views for touch events ?

PS : I have tried splitMotionEvent to no avail

Answer (score 3):

make sure either the `onTouchEvent` or the `dispatchTouchEvent` of your custom layout returns true at the `ACTION_DOWN` happens, and then your custom layout will recieve the `ACTION_MOVE` and `ACTION_UP` later.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue where I were tracking the tap and swipe using `OnTouchClickListener`.

I solved it by dispatching the touch to the parent and the view itself to ignore the upcoming event (so that its sibling's touch/click gets called). If the event is not to be ignored, consume it.

The code looks like this:

```
touchTrackingView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // do not consume this event so the sibling gets the touch/click
        if (mIgnoreNextTouchEvent) {
            mIgnoreNextTouchEvent = false;
            return false;
        }
        // TODO do what you need to do with the touch

        // next touch should be ignored so that
        // the sibling gets their touch/click invoked  
        mIgnoreNextTouchEvent = true;
        ((View) v.getParent()).dispatchTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }
});
```